# Get\Set multiple list data form SP On-Premises site to SP online site Using SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-on-prem, sp-online

I have one SharePoint On-Premises site which is accessible outside of my server. I already have few lists & libraries created on that site which I am using.

I have one Office 365 SharePoint subscription where I am using some modern inbuilt as well as custom web-parts.

In one of my Web-part, I have a form & I want data from SP On-Premises lists (E.G. Countries, Cities, etc.) to bind into drop-down available in SPFx form. I also want to post (save) form data to SharePoint On-Premises list (e.g. Customer Information).

Kindly help me by providing detailed information about How can I perform my operations.

I am using only SPFx solution so Kindly provide me the solution for my SPFx solution only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design an Azure function or self-hosting web service that will connect to SP On-prem and get or post data from/to a list. Use the web service in your SPFx web part. If you need to authorize a user making a call to the function, register an Azure AD App and enable authorization for your Function App as described [here](https://www.vrdmn.com/2018/02/sharepoint-framework-calling-aad.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can we directly do something with SPFx webpart to achieve the same? like REST API or any other way?

Comment: Kindly provide me simple & another way to achieve it.

Comment: Create 2 Microsoft flow, One for bulk operation(which will create the record in SharePoint online from the record available in SharePoint on-prem list like Countries, Cities). The second one will trigger whenever any changes made in SharePoint online list. After that, you only need an SPFx form. ;)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry to provide me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one Web API to get/post data using SharePoint On-premises.

I have used **EnableCors** in **ApiController** to avoid CORS related cross domain error while accessing the Web API through SPFx webpart.

I have used simple Ajax call to get/post data by calling different functions & passing the parameters to my few functions.

I have **hosted my Web API to local IIS** & provided one end point URL so I can use same for further use.